# Setting Zoom Level based on Overlays in Ordnance Survey Map

Tags: openlayers-2, ordnance-survey

I am using the Ordnance map as a backdrop in my website. when overlays the WMS from GeoServer, I am unable to increase the zoom level.

This is my code:

```
 var options = {
                maxResolution: 0.55804443359375,
                projection: "EPSG:27700",
                units: 'm'
            };
            map = new OpenSpace.Map('map', options);   

// Define or get the vector layer to be used
var vlayer = osMap.getVectorLayer();
var mlayer = osMap.getMarkerLayer();
vlayer.displayInLayerSwitcher = false;
mlayer.displayInLayerSwitcher = false;


// setup tiled layer
format = 'image/png';
var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Oxford_Example",
                "http://192.168.0.126:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                    transparent: 'true',
                    LAYERS: 'cite:Oxford_ExampleCapture',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: format,
                    tiled: true,
                    tilesOrigin: osMap.maxExtent.left + ',' + osMap.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    singleTile: true,
                    ratio: 1,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:27700': false }
                }
            );


osMap.addLayers([tiled]);


//Show Co-Ordinate on mouse over    
osMap.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

//OverViewMap
var control = new OpenSpace.Control.OverviewMap();
osMap.addControl(control);
control.maximizeControl();

//ScaleBar
osMap.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({ displayClass: 'olControlScaleLine'   }));
//    osMap.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale({ displayClass: 'olControlScale' })); 

//Layer Switcher
//    var layerSwitch = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
var layerSwitch = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({
    div: OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')
});
osMap.addControl(layerSwitch)
```

But i can zoom in this level only. I am unable to the particular feature. See the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you are setting the `maxResolution` property on your map options. Because you are using the OS OpenSpace version of the map there should be no real need to set any properties as sensible defaults for British National Grid will have been applied already.

Don't bother setting your own options and instead simply make the call:

```
map = new OpenSpace.Map('map');
```

Additionally I think you have a conflict in the way you are specifying your tiled layer. You are setting `singleTile` to `true` as an option and also setting `tiled` to `true`. I think you are wanting the layer to be tiled (given the name of the variable) and so you should remove the `singleTile` property from your options block.

I also don't think you need to bother setting the `tilesOrigin` property either.